# replace() is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

why "*name*" is not being replace here?

```js
var foo = '<div>                <label class="required">_1_label__</label><div id="project_frontendbundle_car_1___name__"><div>                <label for="project_frontendbundle_car_carImages___name___position" class="required">Position</label><input type="number" id="project_frontendbundle_car_carImages___name___position" name="project_frontendbundle_car[carImages][__name__][position]" required="required" /></div><div>                <label for="project_frontendbundle_car_carImages___name___fileName">File name</label><input type="text" id="project_frontendbundle_car_carImages___name___fileName" name="project_frontendbundle_car[carImages][__name__][fileName]" maxlength="2000" /></div></div></div>';

var bar = foo.replace('_name_', '1');
$('body').text(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's replaced. But only the first occurrence.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript maybe this help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var bar = foo.replace(/_name_/g, '1');
```

g = Globally replace

Comment: @zilweb This answer replaces the string evaluation with a regular expression.